# In process web-server for MVC2

Tags: asp.net, iis, webserver, cassini, embeddedwebserver

I'm working on a project that requires an in process web server to run the web based UI.
The best option I have come across is [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/)

EDIT: did some tests and noticed that issue isn't synchronous way of processing requests, it has to do with tcp-connects. fiddler shows 1 second as the tcp-connect time.

Are there any alternatives?

These are the main criteria:

- must be in process, or at least
  usable without any installation.
- must be able to process request
  asynchronously.
- distributable for free with an
  open-source project.

I will also accept a patch to fix CassiniDev as an answer ;)

Comment: You state: *" it doesn't process requests asynchronously"*, *"must be able to process request asynchronously."* can you expand on that some more. Are you saying Cassini only supports one request at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I see two points in your question; 1) You don't want to install anything on target deployment system 2)You want to distribute web server bits as free.

Somehow I am not getting the intent behind these points. Why do you want to redistribute web server bits? You can still make you source code open source. Since you have chose MVC2 for your project, you have already vendor locked yourself. AFAIK MVC2 is not available for anything other than Windows+IIS model (well it is [there](https://serverfault.com/questions/132846/configuring-asp-net-mvc2-on-apache-2-2-using-mod-aspdotnet) but do you want to do it that way?). Wherever you are going to host this application, you are already going to have IIS6/7 and according to me you should not worry about webserver.

Let me know if there is any other reason behind this requirement.

Comment: this is going to be an end user app, I think its unreasonable to require users to install IIS on their machines, also Home editions of windows will not allow IIS to be installed.

Comment: End user web apps require only a browser on their machine. It is only disconnected apps which will require some kind of installation on their machines. I am guessing this is what you are trying to achieve and if my guess is right then there is all together a new dimension you will have to deal with. Correct me with my wild guesses.

Comment: the app is a windows service that will be exposing all the ui through a webui.

Answer (score 0):

Keivan,

I am not sure about your specific requirements with this, but I do suggest that you take a look at [C# WebServer](http://webserver.codeplex.com) - A free open sourced project hosted by [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com).

It implements the ASP.NET MVC 2 technology and you can choose view engines between HAML, Spark and the tradition ASP.Net View engine.

The project is implemented in 1 or 2 Dll's (depending on which version you choose) and can be embedded in the installer program, just like any other traditional dll.

To me, it appears to be a stable and reliable project. Hope it will be useful to you as well as anybody else.